# Find the Laurent series and residue of $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ at $z_0 = -\frac{d}{c}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the Laurent series for the given function about the indicated point, and the residue of the function at the point:
>
> $$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\quad \text{at}\quad z_0 = -\frac{d}{c}.$$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Since the point is clearly a simple pole:

$$\lim_{z\to -\frac{d}{c}}\left(z+\frac{d}{c}\right)\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\frac{a\left(-\frac{d}{c}\right)+b}{c}=\frac{bc-ad}{c^2}=-\frac{\Delta}{c^2}$$

with $\,\Delta=$ the given Moebius transformation's determinant.

About the Laurent series:

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{a\left(z+\frac{d}{c}\right)+b-\frac{ad}{c}}{c\left(z+\frac{d}{c}\right)}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{ac\left(z+\frac{d}{c}\right)+bc-ad}{z+\frac{d}{c}}=$$

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\left(\frac{bc-ad}{z+\frac{d}{c}}+ac\right)$$

and if there was a doubt about the residue we can see it  again in the above development.